# skipping incompatible library (lmono) while cross compiling c with mono

Tags: gcc, mono, arm, cross-compiling

Ok for now i managed to call managed code (mono) from native C code
referring to:
http://www.mono-project.com/Embedding_Mono
which works on my host system (x86) ubuntu.
Now i try to crosscompile it for my target (arm) debian system.

Crosscompiler is arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc 2010 from Codesourcery

when i go for:

`arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc 'pkg-config --cflags glib-2.0 --libs mono' -o main.o main.c`

i get

`Sourcery_G++_Lite/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/4.4.1/../../../../arm-none-linux-gnueabi/bin/ld: cannot find -lmono`

so the libmono.so , libmono.a was found in /usr/lib and i go for:

`arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc -L/usr/lib 'pkg-config --cflags glib-2.0 --libs mono' -o main.o main.c`

which results in:

`/Sourcery_G++_Lite/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/4.4.1/../../../../arm-none-linux-gnueabi/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/libmono.so when searching for -lmono`

`/Sourcery_G++_Lite/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/4.4.1/../../../../arm-none-linux-gnueabi/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/libmono.a when searching for -lmono`

`/Sourcery_G++_Lite/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/4.4.1/../../../../arm-none-linux-gnueabi/bin/ld: cannot find -lmono`

somebody has advice?

best regards
Gobliins

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Build libmono for ARM first, instead of trying to use your x86 build.

Comment: Have you built *that* library for ARM yet?

Comment: Build it once for arm, now i dled them from emdebian.